# Characters of permutation representations for $S_4$

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, young-tableaux

I am going through the lecture note [How to get character tables of symmetric groups](http://www.math.umn.edu/~tlawson/old/18.704/symmetric1.pdf).

On page 2, it computes the character table of $S_4$. The procedure starts with building the table of the characters of permutation representations for $S_4$. The table is given below.

[image]

The note says the following about the table.

> The top row lists the different conjugacy classes by way of listing
>   partitions; the left-hand edge lists the different representations we
>   get for different shapes of tabloid. The top line is the trivial
>   representation, while the bottom one is the regular representation.

I am trying to understand what is going on here. It is clear that the columns are the corresponding partitions, hence, the conjugacy classes. $\sigma_\lambda$ for a given shaped $\lambda$ is defined as follows.

[image]

**So, for example, how $\sigma_{3, 1}$ gives $2$ for the partition $2, 1, 1$?**

Comment: Think about a specific element, say $(1,2)$.  How does it act in the four $3,1$ partitions? How many does it fix?

Comment: @SteveD, the four 3,1 partitions are {[2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [3, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]}, Right?

Comment: maybe we are talking past each other, but I think the shape $3,1$ corresponds to a partition of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into a set of size $3$ and a set of size $1$.

Comment: @SteveD, so the partitions are $\left\{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}\right\}$, $\left\{\{1, 2, 4\}, \{3\}\right\}$, $\left\{\{1, 3, 2\}, \{4\}\right\}$, $\left\{\{1, 4, 2\}, \{3\}\right\}$, $\left\{\{2,  3, 4\}, \{1\}\right\}$, and $\left\{\{2, 4, 3\}, \{1\}\right\}$. So, there are six $3, 1$ partitions. Right?

Comment: There are only four... I think you're injecting some kind of order?

Comment: @SteveD, if I do not consider any order, they are: {{1,2,3},{4}}, {{1,2,4},{3}},  {{2,3,4},{1}}, and {{1,4,3},{2}}, right?

Comment: Cool, now how many of those does $(1,2)$ fix?

Comment: @SteveD , {{1,2,3},{4}} and {{1,2,4},{3}}, so 2 partitions - right?

Comment: Yup!            ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @SteveD, so, $\sigma_{3, 1}$ is a set of permutations, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go over how these representations are defined:

We have a certain **partition** of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; this partition is into an *ordered* collection of *unordered* sets.  Such a partition might look like $[\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}]$; note this is exactly the same partition as $[\{3,1\}, \{2,4\}]$, but **not** the same as $[\{2,4\}, \{1,3\}]$. The problem with that last one is the first element of the array is not the same.  All of these partitions have the same **shape**: $2,2$ means an array, with a set of size $2$ in the first spot, and another set of size $2$ in the second spot.

For each such shape, we can define a representation (over $\mathbb{C}$), and the character is what you are calling $\sigma_{\text{shape}}$. That character can be determined for each "permutation type" by simply asking how many partitions (of that shape) it fixes.

Here's a concrete example: for the "permutation type" $2,1,1$, and the shape $2,2$, we can choose any permutation in $S_4$ of that type: let's use $(1,2)$.  The question is then: how many partitions of shape $2,2$ does $(1,2)$ fix? The answer is two: $[\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}]$ and $[\{3,4\}, \{1,2\}]$. Thus the entry in your table, under column $2,1,1$ and row $\sigma_{2,2}$, is $2$.

Comment: Looks like any permutation of type $2, 1, 1$ is going to fix $2$ partitions of shape $2, 2$.

Comment: @omarshebab: yes because they all have the same character values!